# iOS cordova-plugin-camera adds black background on PNG

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, image, cordova

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

When we import a PNG with an alpha (transparent) layer from the Camera Roll it adds a black background automatically.

How can I modify the plugin (or even use JavaScript) to return a Base64 image with a white background instead?

Below is our JavaScript code thus far:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess1, onFail, {
    quality: 100,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
});

function onPhotoDataSuccess1(imageURI) {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    img.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    console.log('Failed because: ' + message, '');
}
```